# AngularJS bootstrap-ui tabs pulling in local html content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have set up a simple application and I want to pull in, for now, a local html file as the content of each tab.  I also only want the 'apple' content to be displayed under the 'Apple' tab and the same for pear keeping my html as simple as possible as in the future more fruits could be added.

Please see the plunker for my current configuration:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6Ey8vbvrq3xzvBhJS7o?p=preview

```
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="getContent($index)" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
  <div ng-hide="!tabs.isLoaded">
  <h1>{{tab.title}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in tabs.content">
      <p>{{item[tab.title]}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="tabs.isLoaded"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
  </tab>
```

My question is, can you help me identify how to only pull in the specific content for each tab that is part of one html file?

Comment: I  didnt find question here -(

Comment: Sorry Petr you are right. I will update to question format :)

Comment: Do you want the result with angular 1.0.8 & ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js? why using  old versions?

Comment: No sorry, I'm using angular 1.3.8 and latest bootstrap-ui, this was just legacy from a plunker I forked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Following on from your comment to Pangolin's answer: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7lwnPLM51QEFJuW5tSIM?p=preview)

JS

```
app.directive("fruit", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "fruit.html"
    };
});
```

HTML

```
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="getContent($index)" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
  <div ng-hide="!tabs.isLoaded">
    <fruit></fruit>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="tabs.isLoaded"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
  </tab>
```

fruit.html (trimmed version)

```
<div ng-show="tab.title=='Apple'">
<h2>Apple</h2>
<p>The apple tree....
</div>

<div ng-show="tab.title=='Pear'">
<h3>Pear</h3>
<p>The pear is 
</div>
```

Comment: This approach seems to work best for my current needs.  What would you do if you wanted to expand this, say there is now a fruit.html and veg.html?

Comment: @ShannaBarnard Depends what you want to do but I guess you would at least create a veg directive and then you would need to know what a tab refers to (i.e. fruit or veg) and then have an ng-show on that: **<fruit ng-show="tabType='fruit'"></fruit> <veg ng-show="tabType='veg'"></veg>**, for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use case for `ng-include`. As per the [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude%20Documentation), it `fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment.`

Use it like this:

**Javascript**

```
$scope.templates = [
  { URL: '/path/to/file.html' },
  { URL: '/path/to/file2.html'}
]
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="template in templates">
  <div ng-include="template.URL">
    <!-- Template markup goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And that's it. Just make sure that file.html and file2.html exist, and you can just drag your markup right into each corresponding one.

Comment: That's great but what I really want is to use one html file but only show the relevant sections.

Comment: In that case, ng-show and ng-hide are perfectly acceptable in the way you've used them. Or, if you have server access and are ready for a more advanced topic, check out this tutorial on routing and views: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/